# sed change url in configuration file subing in a variable

Tags: url, variables, sed, substitution

I need to change a line in a configuration file. The line is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/subfolder/subfolder.
```

I am collecting the URL from the client and storing it in a file called variables.sh and including it in the script file that is called to make the change to the configuration file containing the default url listed.

The script is:

```
. variables.sh

echo " $dbuser is database user name "

echo " "

cd /home/$dbuser/ris/config

if [ -f /home/$dbuser/ris/config/slsservers.list ];

   then

        echo "$url is now being added "


        cat slsservers.list | \sed 's|127.0.0.1:8190|$url|g' > slsservers.list.1

           echo "URL changed and temp file slservers.list.1 created"

    else

         echo "slsservers.list missing or corrupt"

 fi
```

The problem is that the output is http://$url/subfolder/subfolder. What do I need to get the collected url substituted in the place of the

```
127.0.0.1:8080?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes. Single quotes make everything "literal", while double quotes will allow variable expansion.

It's well demonstrated [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/), for example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is always the little things.